# How to make a input field visible when a button is clicked or create the same field when a button is clicked for ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

rails newbie here.

this is my current form

```
 <%= f.input :campaign_name , :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 300px'} %>
 <%= f.input :date_range, :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 300px'}%>
 <%= f.label :first_event %>
 <%= f.collection_select :first_event, eventNames, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: true %>
 <br><br><br>
 <%= f.label :second_event %>
 <%= f.collection_select :second_event, eventNames, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: true%>
```

what i want is this, when user clicks "add filter" i want another field to pop up with the same eventNames array as a collection select.I tried to create another button and get it's tag and if its not the submit button and its add filter button render another form.

but this is terribly bad as a interface and as a user experience.

i want my user to be able to remove the second event field at anytime, without having to submit the form.

So i need to add another button in it to remove the newly made visible form.

How can i achieve this

Comment: user can add multiple filters?

Comment: @Mandeep oh you again :), yes user will be able to select multiple filters

Comment: if you had a restriction that a user can only add a single filter then you could have simply show or hide your select by js but since user can add multiple filters so it'll be better if you use ajax for it

Comment: @Mandeep well, the user will enter the first ever no matter what, its not accepting null anyway, but if the user clicks add filter, a new input will be shown to user to select another event.I have no knowledge about js or ajax, never used any of them can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in my comment if you have a restriction *that a user could add only a single or lets say a fixed number of filters then you can **simply show and hide your collection by js.*** Your form would have a hidden collection list

```
<%= f.input :campaign_name , :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 300px'} %>
<%= f.input :date_range, :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 300px'}%>
<%= f.label :first_event %>
<%= f.collection_select :first_event, eventNames, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: true %>
<br><br><br>
<%= f.label :second_event %>
<%= f.collection_select :second_event, eventNames, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: true%>
<%= f.label :third_event, class: "hidden" %>
<%= f.collection_select :third_event, eventNames, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: true, class: "hidden"%>
```

**hide your collection by css**

```
.hidden{display: none;}
```

and show it by js when a user click on add filter, assuming it's a link you could do:

```
= link_to "Add Filter", "#", id: "add-filter"

$(document).on("click","#add-filter", function(e){
  $(".hidden").show();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

If user can add multiple filters then you'll need to add them by ajax. For ajax follow these steps:

a. **Create a custom route for your action:**

```
post "/filter" => "your_controller#add_filter", as: "filter"
```

b. **create your link for adding filter:**

```
<%= link_to "Add Filter", filter_path, id: "add-filter", data: {event_id: "2", url: filter_path}%>
```

c. **Get event_id by js and send a ajax request:**

```
$(document).on("click","#add-filter".function(e){
  var eventId = $(this).data("eventId");
  var url = $(this).data("url");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {id: eventId}
  });
})
```

d. **Create add_filter action in your controller:**

```
def add_filter
  @event_id = params[:id]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

e. **Create your new collection and append it by js in *app/views/your_controller/add_filter.js.erb* file**

```
var label = "<%=j label_tag "#{@event_id.humanize}_event" %>" 
var collection = "<%=j collection_select(:resource, "#{@event_id.humanize}_event".to_sym , eventNames, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: true) %>"

$("#form_id").find("select").last().after(label).after(collection);
$("#add-filter").data("eventId","<%=j @event_id + 1 %>");
```

You'll have to use [`humanize`](https://github.com/radar/humanize) or [`number_and_words`](https://github.com/kslazarev/numbers_and_words) to convert your @event_id to words format and also you'll have to change :resource accordingly

Comment: collections or the problem for the first one is they don't become hidden.Only labels are effected by that class definition @mandeep

Comment: @railsnewbie have to check but it should work on select as well.

Comment: it turned out i had to give a div and assign class in that div, it worked thank you now i will try to make it with appear.But wouldn't  a link_to post a submit?

Comment: @railsnewbie no it won't as for the URL option in link_to we are using '#' and also we are disable your links normal behaviour by js by e.preventDefault()